# Why value of the list of lists changing even without any direct reference of it?

Tags: python, list, matrix

I wrote a python code using list of lists as an adjacency matrix called matrix. But when I used the copy of this matrix to create an instance of an experiment and then modified its value, what I noticed was not only copy of matrix was modified but also the original copy "matrix".

Following is the chunk of the code where I did change the value of copy of the matrix called "acopy". With every change made in the value of "acopy"; "adummy" and "matrix" also changed.

```
def main():
    n = 20  
    k = 4 

    matrix = [[0 for x in xrange(n)] for x in xrange(n)]

    matrix[0][n-2], matrix[0][n-1] = 1,1
    matrix[1][n-1], matrix[n-1][n-2] = 1,1

    for i in xrange(n-2):
        matrix[i][i+1] = 1
        matrix[i][i+2] = 1

        if i - 2 >= 0:
            matrix[i][i-1], matrix[i][i-2] = 1,1

    for i in xrange(n):
        for j in xrange(n):
            if matrix[i][j] == 1 or matrix[j][i]==1:
                matrix[i][j], matrix[j][i] = 1,1

    aver_cluster = []
    char_length = []
    probs = []

    adummy = matrix

    for rewiring_prob in drange(0.00, 1.00, 0.001):
        probs.append(rewiring_prob)
        acopy = [[0 for x in xrange(n)] for x in xrange(n)]
        acopy = adummy

        for p in xrange(1, k/2 +1):
            for x in xrange(n):
                rand_prob = random.random()

                if rand_prob < rewiring_prob:
                    b = random.randint(0,n-1)

                    if acopy[x][b] != 1 and x != b and x+p < n:
                        acopy[x][b], acopy[b][x] = 1,1
                        acopy[x][x+p], acopy[x+p][x] = 0,0
                    elif acopy[x][b] != 1 and x != b and x+p >= n:
                        acopy[x][b], acopy[b][x] = 1,1
                        acopy[x][x+p-n], acopy[x+p-n][x] = 0,0          

    return 2
```

My question is how to keep value of original copy constant?
Secondly, why it is happening? That is without any reference of original list, why it is being modified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`acopy = adummy` creates a reference to the list, not a copy, you need `acopy = adummy[:]` to make a copy.

```
In [7]: adummy = [1,2,3]

In [8]: acopy = adummy

In [9]: adummy is acopy
Out[9]: True

In [10]: acopy = adummy[:]

In [11]: adummy is acopy
Out[11]: False
```

`acopy = adummy` makes acopy point to the same object in memory so any changes to `acopy` will effect `adummy` and vice versa

For a list of lists use [deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy):

```
import copy
acopy = copy.deepcopy(adummy)
```

`adummy = matrix` is also just creating a reference to the `matrix` list so you will need to do the same.

Comment: `acopy = adummy[:]` will only make a shallow copy, and so won't help much with a list of lists.